# AWS SAM build container images pile up over time, bloating my hard drive. Is there a straightforward way to purge the old ones?

Tags: aws-sam, resource-cleanup

I am developing a serverless webapp using AWS SAM. It has Lambda functions that are built using containers to replicate the actual SAM runtime environment.

I recently stumbled upon issues about SAM builds crashing with the dreaded `No space left on device` error. Turned out that SAM regularly downloads updated versions of the runtime Docker images, and does not clean up the older ones afterwards.

A listing of the Docker images on my system has shown that I had a dozen of the same one, for instance a nodejs-16 environment. I had to manually purge the superfluous images one by one, and reclaimed about 30 GB on my hard drive by doing so. This is enormous.

Is there a straightforward way using SAM to purge the old images, or instruct it to do so automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no such built-in mechanism yet.

So, I worked my way as follows.

**Word of caution: this solution fits my use case but may be destructive if you are not careful.** My main use of Docker is for Lambda, and a couple extra containers for a local development database server. Read the commands and understand what they do first.

First, delete all the leftover containers from previous `aws sam local` or `aws sam start-api` runs. They have in common that the command that runs them is `/var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie`

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a --format '{{.ID}} {{.Command}}' --no-trunc | grep "/var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Then, we can purge the dangling images i.e. those not attached to a container anymore

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q)
```

Alternately, it is possible to do the following to purge the leftover images. But I am not sure about the blast radius in case you have other Docker stuff lying around you may want to keep.

```
docker image prune -a
```

Enjoy the reclaimed gigabytes!